# Как останавливать mediaPlayer при открытии нового потока/файла

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Я стримлю аудио через `mediaPlayer`, при нажатии на одну из кнопок станций (радио) я передаю значения потока и т.д, но если нажать на кнопку станции и сразу закрыть, поток не успевает прогрузиться и управление им становится невозможным и при нажатии на другую кнопку станции 2 потока смешиваются.

Как мне останавливать `mediaPlayer` при открытии новой станции? Пробовал передавать
byte с определенном значением, принимать его в плеере и если оно равно заданному значению, то `mediaPlayer.stop();`, однако не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам проще сделать переменную mediaPlayer статической, а не создавать каждый раз новую, а управление разнести по методам. К примеру:

```
    public void Stop() {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying())
            mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.onlyLog(this, "Ошибка остановки плеера" + ex.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Тут конечно двумя словами не обойдёшься. Есть [вот отличная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/339416/) на хабре